# Why does the IEnumerable<T>.Select() works in 1 of 2 cases ? Can not be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, select, ienumerable, inferred-type

I get this **error message:**

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

The first method has no problems using a `IEnumerable<T>.Select()` ?
Where is the problem with the 2nd method?

```
private void GetPupilsForSchoolclass()
{
   ObservableCollection<PupilViewModel> pupilsOC = new ObservableCollection<PupilViewModel>
   (                            _adminRepo.GetPupilsBySchoolclassId(_selectedSchoolclass.SchoolclassId).Select(p => new       PupilViewModel(p, _adminRepo))
   );
   SelectedSchoolclass.PupilListViewModel = pupilsOC;
}

private void GetDocumentsForPupil()
{
                ObservableCollection<Document> documentsOC = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
                IEnumerable<Document> documents = _docRepo.GetDocumentsByPupilId(_selectedPupil.Id);
                documents.Select(doc => documentsOC.Add(doc));
                SelectedPupil.Documents.DocumentList = documentsOC;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`documentsOC.Add` returns `void`.
It doesn't make any sense (and is impossible) to write `.Select<Something, void>(...)`.

What you're trying to do cannot work in the first place; `Select` is lazy and doesn't call your function until you enumerate the results.

You should use a regular `foreach` loop.

Comment: hell... within a minute a storm of answers comin` downtown :P ah yes was too fixin on the viewmodel but an IEnumerable is enough for the Ctor of an OCollection => ObservableCollection<Document> documentsOC = new ObservableCollection<Document>(_docRepo.GetDocumentsByPupilId(_selectedPupil.Id));

Answer (score 6):

The Error seems The Return statement missing when you select an Items from the collection.

Example:

```
collection = nonLabors.Select(item =>
                {
                    item.Travel_Miles = item.Travel_Miles_Original != null ? decimal.Parse(item.Travel_Miles_Original) : 0;
                    return item;
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I *suspect* that `Add` returns `void` - is that right? If so there is no way of projecting that to a `Func<,>` - only to an `Action<T>` - and `Select` wants the `Func<,>`.

`Select` is **not** the same as an indirect `foreach

Answer (score 1):

What is the return type of `ObservableCollection<Document>.Add`?  Typically an `Add` method returns void.  You can't use LINQ `Select` to execute a procedure for all elements, only a function that returns something (else where would the return value of `Select` come from?).  Instead you can use LINQ `ForEach` or the C# foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Select is *not* a replacement for a foreach. Use this instead:

```
ObservableCollection<Document> documentsOC = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
IEnumerable<Document> documents = _docRepo.GetDocumentsByPupilId(_selectedPupil.Id);
foreach(var doc in documents)
{
    documentsOC.Add(doc);
}
SelectedPupil.Documents.DocumentList = documentsOC;
```

Comment: it is if you just want to get doc to put it somewhere, no big logic/computation is need here for that I would use foreach.